# Ionic 4 fails to load on mobile once i add Google Firebase to the project

Tags: android, angular, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework

My ionic 4 project works great on chrome, devapp and even after compiling to apk.

But once I add firebase config it fails to load using both `devapp` or even after compiling to `apk`.

here is how I add `firebase`:

first of all, I install it using `npm install @angular/fire firebase --save`

My **environments.ts** it looks like:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  firebase: {
    apiKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    authDomain: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx.firebaseapp.com',
    databaseURL: 'https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com',
    projectId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    storageBucket: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.appspot.com',
    messagingSenderId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
  }
};
```

then I add these lines with trailing `<<<<` to my **app.module.ts** :

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { environment } from '../environments/environment';   <<<<
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';   <<<<<
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/firestore';  <<<<


@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase), <<<<
    AngularFirestoreModule   <<<<
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

once I finish this, the app is no longer working on mobile ( white death screen)

And that is what I get when I use the chrome remote dev. tools:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'HTMLElement': Please use the 'new' operator, this DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function.
```

Comment: It looks good to me, if you are doing a production build make sure you have the firebase settings in the environment.prod file too.

Do you see console log error when testing on the device with Chrome debug tools?

Comment: yes that is what i get in chrome remote debugging :
`Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'HTMLElement': Please use the 'new' operator, this DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function.`

Comment: It’s too hard to tell without a repo to recreate, but that error almost seems as if it trickled up from something stencil related in the ionic components